# Astronomical events and Celebrations

Tags: star, the-sun, planet, the-moon, earth

In the past people celebrated important astronomical events and some of those events are still celebrated in some cultures and traditions. 
For example: March/September equinox, New Moon, Winter/Summer solstice.

I am looking for a list of astronomical events that people celebrated in the past. Do you know any other important astronomical events that were celebrated in the past?

Comment: More examples. 
New year's Eve: https://earthsky.org/astronomy-essentials/star-sirius-torchbearer-of-the-new-year
Halloween: https://earthsky.org/astronomy-essentials/halloween-derived-from-ancient-celtic-cross-quarter-day

Comment: I couldn't find any great sources, but if you google `holidays based on astronomy` (without quotes), you'll find a few sources that might help a little.

Answer (score 1):

The summer and winter solstices, and the vernal and autumnal equinoxes were venerated for a very long time throughout Western Europe.

Solar and Lunar eclipses where so significant, from a religious perspective, that many efforts were made to predict their occurrences well into the modern era.

Cometary close-approaches also were seen as omens and portents (see also the star of Christmas in Judeo-Christian circles), as were detectable nova and super-nova.

There are probably more, but I can't think of what they might be right now.  Humans have been obsessed with the heavens since humans could human, so...

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by "humans could human"? Lol

Comment: It's a play on words in English, meant to indicate that we have been doing a thing for as long as we have been around